# WordPress custom post type cannot access child page

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

The below successfully allows me to use **Programmes** and **Programme FAQ** in my WordPress website as **custom post types** but I'm struggling with the permalinks of the pages.

When I create a new *FAQ page* I set the parent as a **programme** this is fine, but its the permalink that I cannot seem to get working.

If by example a programme was called **Football** I would visit `domain.com/programmes/football`then I would create a Programme FAQ with the same name **Football** and set the parent as Football from the programme and the permalink for the faq would become `domain.com/programme_faq/football/football`

When I try to visit that page it comes up as a 404 not found. If I remove the parent option from the FAQ page then the permalink becomes `domain.com/programme_faq/football` and this works.

Ideally I would prefer the pages made in **Programme FAQ** to end up as `domain.com/programmes/football/faq`

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_programmes' );
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_programmes_faq' );

function register_cpt_programmes() {

    $labels = array( 
        'name'               => __( 'Programmes', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'      => __( 'single programme name', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add Programme', '${4:Name}', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add Programme', 'text_domain}' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit this Programme', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Programme', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Programme', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Programmes', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No Programmes found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Programmes found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent single post type name:', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'          => __( 'Programmes', 'text_domain' ),
    );

    $args = array( 
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'hierarchical'        => true,
        'description'         => 'description',
        //'taxonomies'          => array( 'category' ),
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        //'menu_icon'         => '',
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'query_var'           => true,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'rewrite'             => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page', 
        'supports'            => array( 
            'title', 'editor', 'author', 'page-attributes', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'revisions', 'comments'
        ),
        'rewrite' => array(
            'with_front' => false,
            'slug'       => 'programmes'
        )
    );

    register_post_type( 'programmes', $args );
}

function register_cpt_programmes_faq() {

    $labels = array( 
        'name'               => __( 'Programme FAQ', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'      => __( 'single programme faq', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add Programme FAQ', '${4:Name}', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add Programme FAQ', 'text_domain}' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit this Programme FAQ', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Programme FAQ', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Programme FAQ', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Programme FAQ', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No Programme FAQs found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Programmes FAQs found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent single post type name:', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'          => __( 'Programme FAQ', 'text_domain' ),
    );

    $args = array( 
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'hierarchical'        => true,
        'description'         => 'description',
        //'taxonomies'          => array( 'category' ),
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        //'menu_icon'         => '',
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'query_var'           => true,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'rewrite'             => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page', 
        'supports'            => array( 
            'title', 'editor', 'author', 'page-attributes', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'revisions', 'comments'
        ),
        'rewrite' => array(
            'with_front' => false,
            'slug'       => 'programme_faq'
        )
    );

    register_post_type( 'programme_faq', $args );
}
add_action('admin_menu', function() {
    remove_meta_box('pageparentdiv', 'programme_faq', 'normal');
});

add_action('add_meta_boxes', function() {
    add_meta_box('programmes-parent', 'Programmes', 'programmes_attributes_meta_box', 'programme_faq', 'side', 'high');
});

function programmes_attributes_meta_box($post) {
    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object($post->post_type);
    if ( $post_type_object->hierarchical ) {
        $pages = wp_dropdown_pages(array('post_type' => 'programmes', 'selected' => $post->post_parent, 'name' => 'parent_id', 'show_option_none' => __('(no parent)'), 'sort_column'=> 'menu_order, post_title', 'echo' => 0));
        if ( ! empty($pages) ) {
            echo $pages;
        } // end empty pages check
    } // end hierarchical check.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is my first time answering on Stack Overflow. Please pardon formatting and spelling issues.**

**SUMMARY:**

The key steps in reaching a solution are documented in the code. Here is a summary:

1. Register the custom post types
2. Add a "Parent Programme" meta box on the EDIT screen
3. Add a rewrite rule so WordPress properly parses the custom URL structure
4. Filter the permalink so links to FAQ pages are rendered properly

**CODE:**

```
// 1a. register the Programmes post type
function register_cpt_programmes()
{
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => __('Programmes', 'text_domain'),
        'singular_name'      => __('single programme name', 'text_domain'),
        'add_new'            => _x('Add Programme', '${4:Name}', 'text_domain'),
        'add_new_item'       => __('Add Programme', 'text_domain}'),
        'edit_item'          => __('Edit this Programme', 'text_domain'),
        'new_item'           => __('New Programme', 'text_domain'),
        'view_item'          => __('View Programme', 'text_domain'),
        'search_items'       => __('Search Programmes', 'text_domain'),
        'not_found'          => __('No Programmes found', 'text_domain'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Programmes found in Trash', 'text_domain'),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __('Parent single post type name:', 'text_domain'),
        'menu_name'          => __('Programmes', 'text_domain'),
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'description'         => 'description',
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'query_var'           => true,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'rewrite'             => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page', 
        'supports'            => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'author',
            'page-attributes',
            'thumbnail',
            'excerpt',
            'custom-fields',
            'revisions',
            'comments'
        ),
        'rewrite' => array(
            'with_front' => false,
            'slug'       => 'programmes'
        )
    );
    register_post_type('programmes', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'register_cpt_programmes');

// 1b. register the Programme FAQ post type
function register_cpt_programme_faq()
{
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => __('Programme FAQ', 'text_domain'),
        'singular_name'      => __('single programme faq', 'text_domain'),
        'add_new'            => _x('Add Programme FAQ', '${4:Name}', 'text_domain'),
        'add_new_item'       => __('Add Programme FAQ', 'text_domain}'),
        'edit_item'          => __('Edit this Programme FAQ', 'text_domain'),
        'new_item'           => __('New Programme FAQ', 'text_domain'),
        'view_item'          => __('View Programme FAQ', 'text_domain'),
        'search_items'       => __('Search Programme FAQ', 'text_domain'),
        'not_found'          => __('No Programme FAQs found', 'text_domain'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Programmes FAQs found in Trash', 'text_domain'),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __('Parent single post type name:', 'text_domain'),
        'menu_name'          => __('Programme FAQ', 'text_domain'),
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'description'         => 'description',
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'query_var'           => true,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'rewrite'             => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page', 
        'supports'            => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'author',
            'page-attributes',
            'thumbnail',
            'excerpt',
            'custom-fields',
            'revisions',
            'comments'
        ),
        'rewrite' => array(
            'with_front' => false,
            'slug'       => 'programme_faq'
        )
    );
    register_post_type('programme_faq', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'register_cpt_programme_faq');

// 2a. meta box - add a custom meta box on the Programme FAQ edit page
function pfaq_add_meta_boxes($post)
{
    add_meta_box('pfaq-parent', 'Parent Programme', 'pfaq_parent_meta_box', $post->post_type, 'side', 'core');
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes_programme_faq', 'pfaq_add_meta_boxes');

// 2b. select box - add a select input inside the Parent Programme meta box
function pfaq_parent_meta_box($post)
{
    $parents = get_posts(
        array(
            'post_type'   => 'programmes',
            'orderby'     => 'title',
            'order'       => 'ASC',
            'numberposts' => -1
        )
    );

    if(!empty($parents))
    {
        echo '<select name="parent_id" class="widefat">';

        foreach($parents as $parent)
        {
            printf('<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>', esc_attr($parent->ID), selected($parent->ID, $post->post_parent, false), esc_html($parent->post_title));
        }

        echo '</select>';
    }
}

// 3. rewrite rule - teach WordPress to parse the custom URL pattern
function pfaq_rewrite_rule()
{
    add_rewrite_rule('^programmes/([^/]+)/faq/?', 'index.php?programme_faq=$matches[1]-faq', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'pfaq_rewrite_rule');

// 4. permalink - filter all Programme FAQ permalinks to match the desired URL pattern
function pfaq_post_type_link($post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample)
{
    if($post->post_type == 'programme_faq')
    {
        $parent = get_post($post->post_parent);
        $post_link = get_bloginfo('url') . '/programmes/' . $parent->post_name . '/faq';
    }

    return $post_link;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'pfaq_post_type_link', 1, 4);
```

**NOTES:**

I've repeated the code from the original question to reflect a couple of important changes:

- the solution requires NON-HIERARCHICAL post types
- renamed functions for consistency
- corrected issues in the meta box code
- corrected "programme" vs. "programmes" where functionality was impacted

The prefix "pfaq" was chosen as most of the customizations revolve around the "Programme FAQ" post type.

**CREDITS:**

WordPress Core, WordPress Codex, @justintadlock, @tareq_cse